# NeoVi Fire and Raspberry Pi with Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, can-bus

I am attempting to create a program that can read DTC codes from CAN-Bus devices connected to a Raspberry Pi via a USB to Serial connection.  I am testing with a NeoVi Fire that I have hooked up, and currently I am able to send and read serial signals to the device to control car seat heating and cooling units I have attached to it via said serial port.

Now I need to expand what I have into requesting codes from the CAN unit so I am seeing if Python-CAN can do what I need it to (since the rest of my program is all written in Python).

I also went and installed the PyNeoVi library since I am using the NeoVi unit, and I am running into a problem while attempting to use one of the test files with the PyNeoVi repository.  This is the code for the test file:

```
import neovi.neodevice as neodevice
import neovi.ecu as ecu
import neovi.spec as spec
import neovi.neovi as neovi
import json


neodevice.init_api()
dev = neodevice.find_devices(neovi.NEODEVICE_FIRE)[0]
dev.open()


input_file = open('vehicle.spec', 'rt')
data = json.load(input_file, object_hook = spec.from_json)

hvac = ecu.ECU(data['ECUs']['HVAC'], dev)

wanted_values = ['Blower Speed Output', 'External Ambient Temperature', 'Left Solar Radiation Sensor', 'Cabin Temperature']

for value_name in wanted_values:
    result = hvac.read_data_by_id(value_name)['value']
    print("%s = %.1f %s" % (value_name, result[0], result[1]))

dev.close()
```

The error I am getting is:

```
OSError: libicsneoAPI.so.0.1.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It sounds like I am missing a dependency, but I am not sure where do download said dependency from.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the Intrepid Product Drivers installed.

See https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interfaces/neovi.html and let me know if you still experience any issues.